# Hash lookup table primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to populate a database with a set of $string,md5($string) CSV files, essentially a hash lookup table.

My question is:
 should I use the string as Primary key? The hash? Add an extra ID column?

I think the hash would be good since thats what I'll be asking the database, but hashes can collide, Strings should be unique anyways (to save space) but I wanted a second opinion on it.

I'm asking with performance in mind considering it will be populated with at least 35GB of data. So really any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using a SERIAL id field, so Icould count how many entrys I had.

The initial problem started as I thought you coul only index columns with PRIMARY KEY.

So problem solved now, I just indexed properly and performance is great!

Comment: You can **not** use a `serial` column to "count" how many rows you have. The numbers are **not** guaranteed to be gapless and if you delete rows those ids will **not** be re-used.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the heads up, didn't realize that. In this specific case though, I believe I won't be deleting any entries.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is going to be used for foreign key references, then I would not (necessarily) recommend hashing.  You can:

- Create a serial (auto-incremented) id column as the primary key.
- Create a unique index on `name`.

This should facilitate lookups in the table as well as verifying that `name` is unique.  It is better to use fixed-length numbers for foreign key references than variable length strings.

If you use a hash value and really do not want duplicates, then you would need some mechanism for distinguishing between different strings with the same hash value.  A natural choice would be some sort of incremental counter -- but that would leave you pretty close to the solution with just the counter and no hash.  I don't, per se, see the advantage of storing such a hash value in the table.

Comment: I do password auditing and statistics and I find myself cracking hashes just to find they were weak passwords, I figured I would just precompute all possible combinations on what easy password means. (Length, charsets, etc.) my query would be SELECT string FROM table WHERE hash = 'hash'

Comment: @John . . . But a weak password could hash the same as a strong one.  Besides, I think there are too many rules -- for instance, repeating a letter "n" times or using someone's name and so on.

Comment: A hash collision is very unlikely, even in MD5. Also, yes I have considered that "n" thing. My question was regarding performance.